# Google Analytics Date/Hour/Time Stamp

Tags: google-analytics

I have a goal and I would like to see the date/hour/minute the goal occurred. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

December 2019 update : Create a custom report with up to 5 dimensions, such as Screen Name + Source + Date + Hour + Minute

And seemingly endless number of metrics, such as Pageviews.

Use Filters to isolate the data you're after, such as Include>Screen Name>Regex>AWordInYourURLlikeConfirmation

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom report with Goal XX Completions (ga:goalXXCompletions) as a metric and Minute Index (ga:nthMinute) as a dimension.

**Minute Index** means *index for each minute in the specified date range. Index for the first minute of first day (i.e., start-date) in the date range is 0, 1 for the next minute, and so on.*

Instead of Minute Index you can use three: Date (ga:date), Hour (ga:hour) and Minute (ga:minute).

Remember that goals fire once per session per goal.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. Follow up question - is it possible to export all data down to the day/hour/minute level? I'm just seeing a way to export by day/hour, or hour/minute.

Comment: Use a flat table type (in report content section in creating custom report), then you can add up to 7 dimensions in single report.